# npm init gives Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, npm-init

I've used node and npm before in one or two projects, but I'm not really proficient with it. I now want to initialize a new project on MacOS by using `npm init`, but I get this:

```
$ npm init
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:26:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?

[EDIT]

I just tried the suggestion by @kgangadhar , but the result is the same:

```
$ sudo npm install -g process-nextick-args
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:26:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

Comment: what's your npm version?

Comment: and node.js version

Comment: Same problem for me. I'm using node v9.8.0, can't check npm version since it throws the mentioned error! Don't know what happened in the meanwhile, been using npm for years now ...